# Rbbg blpConnection() java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: r, bloomberg

I've reinstalled bloomberg API a couple times and used file paths in the raw `blpConnect()` code for both bloomberg API files and blpwrapper file. I'm not sure what is wrong with the connection

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) 
rJava Version 0.9-6 
Rbbg Version 0.5.3 
Java environment initialized successfully.
Adding C:\blp\API\APIv3\JavaAPI\v3.8.8.2\lib\blpapi3.jar to Java classpath
 Show Traceback
```

Rerun with Debug

```
Error in .jnew("org/findata/blpwrapper/Connection", java.log.level) : 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Update `Rbbg` via

```
install.packages("Rbbg", repos="http://r.findata.org")
```

then run `conn` as

```
conn <- blpConnect(log.level="off")
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it still seems to have a bug. Any ideas for this error? > library(Rbbg)
> library(rJava)
> conn <- blpConnect(log.level="off")
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) 
rJava Version 0.9-6 
Rbbg Version 0.5.3 
Java environment initialized successfully.
Looking for most recent blpapi3.jar file...
Adding C:\blp\API\APIv3\JavaAPI\v3.8.8.2\lib\blpapi3.jar to Java classpath
Error in blpConnect.Java("off", NULL, TRUE, NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, NULL) : 
  blpwrapper jar file not found at  please report this as a bug
>